# Replace certain objects that are greater than 100 from a list with the input then

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have to take every 5th element of the list, multiply it by 2 and place the results into a new list then merge the two lists.

I don't even know how to start it let alone carry on.

### Edit

After a break this is as much as I could do with 0 knowledge.

```
L = [ 10, 2, 56, 33, 23, 1, 564, 32, 122, 42, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 54, 5, 9, 1, 65, 254 ]

x = int(input("Insert number here: "))

for i in range(0, int(len(L))):
    if L[i] > 100:
       L.pop(i)    
       L.insert(i, x)
       print(L)
```

Comment: Then again what I've written doesn't work. It does not replace the numbers greater than 100 but at least inserts the input.

Comment: What exactly does "place the results into a new list" mean? Does that mean only every 5th element? And what does "merge the two lists" mean? In short, can we please have a [mcve]?

Comment: You can just modify a list element with `L[i] = <new value>`. No need for pop and insert.

Comment: Maybe you could give the expected result given that list `L`? (or a smaller example input)

Comment: @Aran-Fey Means the result (every 5th element *2) should go there.

Comment: @9769953 I know I can modify it but this is the task my "teacher" has given me so I have to complete it that way.

Comment: Your title conflicts with what you wrote in the question. Both say different things

Comment: @Bazingaa Care to elaborate?

Comment: Can you **show us** your desired output? Rather than explaining it, this will avoid the confusion, @jdehesa has asked for this too.

Comment: I don't see any mention of requiring the use of pop and insert, and you indicate the code is yours, so I don't see a reason to not simply use `L[i] = x`.

Comment: Yes. Your title says replace objects greater than 100 and replace with user input. But your question says take every 5th element and double it. Do you see any similarity between the two?

Comment: @Bazingaa the title and first paragraph run together, and should be read as the total assignment: replace values > 100, then take every 5th element, multiply those values by 2 and add to new list, merge the original and new list.

Comment: Then you should first make this clear in your question and update/edit it in the interest of others here. You might then be able to get more concrete inputs

Comment: i think he wants to merge  2 list . 1st list will have every 5th element doubled. and second one will have x( given input) in place of elements which are greater than 100. You really should write your question properly

Comment: @jpp  For example: your input is 5. All numbers in L that are greater than 100 will be replaced with 5. Then you take every 5th element of L, multiply it by 2 and place the results into a brand new list (let's name it K). After all this you merge L and K

Comment: @jdehesa ^ I hope my comments clarifies it a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion based on your clearest explanation. I hope it matches your expectations:

```
L = [ 10, 2, 56, 33, 23, 1, 564, 32, 122, 42, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 54, 5, 9, 1, 65, 254 ]

# Ask for user input
myInput = int(input("Enter a number: "))  # ex: I entered 5

# Replace the numbers in L that are greater than 100 with the input number
L = [myInput if i > 100 else i for i in L]
print(L) # ex: [10, 2, 56, 33, 23, 1, 5, 32, 5, 42, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 54, 5, 9, 1, 65, 5]

# Take every 5th element of L, multiply it by 2 and place the results into a brand new list K
K = [value*2 for i,value in enumerate(L,1) if i % 5 == 0]
print(K) # ex: [46, 84, 6, 18]

# Merge L and K into LK
LK = L + K
print(LK) # ex: [10, 2, 56, 33, 23, 1, 5, 32, 5, 42, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 54, 5, 9, 1, 65, 5, 46, 84, 6, 18]
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work very well.

Comment: Of course it does, my friend ! You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to your problem from what I understood from the above comments. In case this is not you want, let me know and I will update accordingly. I am using list comprehensions here. I used `(i+1)%5` to access 5th index because the index starts from `0` in python.

```
L = [ 10, 2, 56, 33, 23, 1, 564, 32, 122, 42, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 54, 5, 9, 1, 65, 254 ]
x = int(input("Insert number here: "))

L1 = [x if i > 100 else i for i in L]
L2 = [2*j if (i+1)%5==0 else j for i, j in enumerate(L1)]

L_output = L1 + L2
print (L1)
print (L2)
print (L_output)
```

**Output**

```
Insert number here: 6
[10, 2, 56, 33, 23, 1, 6, 32, 6, 42, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 54, 5, 9, 1, 65, 6]
[10, 2, 56, 33, 46, 1, 4, 32, 4, 84, 3, 4, 2, 1, 6, 2, 1, 54, 5, 18, 1, 65, 4]
[10, 2, 56, 33, 23, 1, 6, 32, 6, 42, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 54, 5, 9, 1, 65, 6, 10, 2, 56, 33, 46, 1, 4, 32, 4, 84, 3, 4, 2, 1, 6, 2, 1, 54, 5, 18, 1, 65, 4]
```

Comment: Hey. So I ran it but  "  L2 = [2*j if (i+1)%5==0 else j for i, j in enumerate(L_1)]
NameError: name 'L_1' is not defined "

Comment: Yes, I updated it. Plz replace `L_1` by `L1`

Comment: Thank you. This and Laurent's answer were exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Do you just want the 5th element from `L1`? If yes, then replace `L2 = [2*j if (i+1)%5==0 else j for i, j in enumerate(L1)]` by `L2 = [2*j for i, j in enumerate(L1) if (i+1)%5==0 ]`

Comment: @Bazingaa We both deserve to be the accepted answer. I give you my upvote.

Comment: @LaurentH. I can't accept both, can I?

Comment: No, you can't. You can only change. The last click will define the accepted answer.

Comment: @LaurentH.: That's very ethical and kind of you. Much appreciated! I give you mine too.

Comment: Ah foul word. The pressure is real.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this helps :

```
l1 = range(100)
l2 = [l1[x]*2  if x%5==4 else l1[x] for x in range(len(l1)) ]
print(l2)
```

It modifies only every fifth element : thus, these on 4th, 9th, 14th... etc place. (so, x modulo 5 equals 4) The other elements stay as they were.